# Download zip files using URL

Tags: go

Trying to download zip file from the below URL:

https://www.3gpp.org/ftp//Specs/archive/29_series/29.512/29.512-f20.zip

I tried downloading using `http.Get` in Go:

```
resp, err := http.Get(specUrl)
if err != nil {
    return err
}
```

Need help in downloading the zip file.

Comment: the link is saying that the directory is not found

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http.get can allow to download whatever files. But the link of the question points to a file that is not found. No error is thrown, but the status code is not 200 (ok). The status code of the response has to be checked before proceeding and creating the file got from the response.

```
func main() {
    specUrl := "https://www.3gpp.org/ftp//Specs/archive/29_series/29.512/29.512-f20.zip"
    resp, err := http.Get(specUrl)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("err: %s", err)
    }


    defer resp.Body.Close()
    fmt.Println("status", resp.Status)
    if resp.StatusCode != 200 {
        return
    }

    // Create the file
    out, err := os.Create("test.zip")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("err: %s", err)
    }
    defer out.Close()

    // Write the body to file
    _, err = io.Copy(out, resp.Body)
    fmt.Printf("err: %s", err)
}
```

Comment: Going to url https://www.3gpp.org/ftp//Specs/archive/29_series/29.512/ lists all the files, and when I copy the link it give me https://www.3gpp.org/ftp/Specs/archive/29_series/29.512/29512-f20.zip, also the file gets downloaded.

Comment: So change the url to reflect what you want for instance https://www.3gpp.org/ftp/Specs/archive/29_series/29.512/29512-000.zip, https://www.3gpp.org/ftp/Specs/archive/29_series/29.512/29512-010.zip, etc...